# I would like to try installing Ubuntu onto my laptop and don't know how

Tags: boot, drivers, system-installation, acer

I have an Acer Aspire E15.
The full designation is E5-551-T1MK
It has an AMD A10-7300 processor, 8GB of DDR3 L RAM and AMD Radeon R6 graphics.
It also unfortunately has Windows10 on it.
I would like to remove Windows10 and run Ubuntu instead, but I am no tech or "IT guy" so am not sure of the correct procedure. (eg do I install Ubuntu and then erase Win10? Or do I wipe Win10 first?)
I have heard of people having issues running Ubuntu on Acer laptops, trackpads suddenly don't work, Some of the RAM can't be seen by the processor, the machine runs hot, battery life down... These are issues that I am hoping to avoid!!  After all, who wants to wind up with a machine that runs worse than it does on Win10?
Does anybody have experience of installing Ubuntu onto Acers laptops?  Is Ubuntu not yet laptop-friendly? Is it just a system for the techs and the desktops?
If I install Ubuntu onto an external USB hdd is there any way to make the computer boot from that so I can get everything working properly with Ubuntu before wiping Win10 from the internal HDD?
Thanks in advance for any help that anyone can provide!!
Can anybody offer advice or assistance? Or both?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the way to install ubuntu using a usb stick.

1. Download the Ubuntu iso file. The latest version of ubuntu is
   available [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)
2. Download [rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) and create a bootable usb drive of ubuntu.
3. Restart windows and boot from the usb device. Press F12 to get the boot menu.

Then you can install or try ubuntu os. Step by step instructions are available [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop)

In the installation, you can configure or format partitions. In that window you can format the windows partition.

Answer (score 0):

You can find all kinds of information on this just by looking for it.

Here's one link: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

I set up Ubuntu 14.04 on my netbook (yes--laptop friendly) with an SD card that I formatted using Linux Live http://www.linuxliveusb.com/

Yes it does offer an option to try it before installing it. It will also handle your old OS, whether you want to delete it, or make a dual boot, or whatever.